# What is Doctrine hydration?

Tags: php, doctrine, hydration

I've read about hydration in doctrine's documentation but I still can't understand what it is.

Could someone please explain?

Comment: Doctrine2 documentation reference explaining HYDRATION:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats

Comment: Not constructive? This is one of the most fundamental concepts for understanding how the Doctrine internals work.

Comment: I think this question should be protected rather than closed.

Comment: @Simon Agree. Question and the accepted answer are both popular, why not move it to _protected_ state then?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Hydration is a method used to return query results. For example:

1. `HYDRATE_ARRAY` - This will return you an array of records that are represented by another array:

   ```
   $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
      ->from('Post p')
      ->setHydrationMode(Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

   $resultSet = $q->execute(); // $resultSet is an array

   foreach ($resultSet as $post) {
       // $post is an array
       echo $post['title'];
   }
   ```
2. `HYDRATE_RECORD` - This will return you an collection ([Doctrine_Collection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/api/1_2)) of objects:

   ```
   $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
      ->from('Post p')
      ->setHydrationMode(Doctrine::HYDRATE_RECORD); // Unnecessary, HYDATE_RECORD is default method

   $resultSet = $q->execute(); // $resultSet is an Doctrine_Collection object

   foreach ($resultSet as $post) {
       // $post is an Post object
       echo $post->getTitle();
       echo $post['title']; // Each Doctrine's Model object implements ArrayAccess interface so this is possible
       echo $post->myCustomMethod();
   }
   ```
3. `HYDRATE_SINGULAR_SCALAR` - Will return the value of first column of query's result:

   ```
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
      ->select('p.created_at')
      ->from('Post p')
      ->where('p.id = ?', 321)
      ->setHydrationMode(Doctrine::HYDRATE_SINGULAR_SCALAR); 

   $createdAt = $q->execute(); // $createdAt has value of first column from first record from result set (eg.: 2008-04-06 21:22:35)
   ```

There is a few more methods , you can read about each in documentation.

Comment: ok..so normally when i use sql it returns a mysql object and i have to use mysqli_fetch_assoc, then sort them by myself and so on...but now its all sorted for me. that is what hydration is about, giving me sorted objects/arrays?

Comment: No, it's not about sorting result (`orderBy()` handle this). It is about *What will your query result*, whether it will be a single scalar value (`HYDRATE_SINGULAR_SCALAR`), an array or arrays where nested arrays represent each database record (`HYDRATE_ARRAY`) or a collection of objects (`HYDRATE_RECORD`). Do [var_dump](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) on query result for each hydration mode - that's the best way to see "how it works?"

Comment: aha..i think i get it now. so it's about what form i want the result to be in: scalar value, arrays or objects? that sounds like a very nice feature. than i dont have to convert them myself from mysqli_object:)

Comment: just a little tip. In 1.2 `HYDRATE_SINGULAR_SCALAR` returns an undefined constant error. `HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR` is right.

Comment: As a note `Doctrine::HYDRATE_RECORD` is now known as `Doctrine::HYDRATE_OBJECT`

Comment: A link to the aforementioned documentation would make this answer more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
$q->fetchOne(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

It will return just a simple array instead of a doctrine collection object.