# Symfony memory issues

Tags: symfony-1.4

I'm having hard time with symfony and cpu/memory leak, i'm new to symfony i don't know if i'm messing any tips or techniques to overcome this problem.

i'm hosting my current symfony project on a vps and it halts almost every other hour.

I would like also to know the answers for these questions :

when i execute a doctrine query using (fetchOne, fetchAll, execute) i get a lot of extra symfony stuff like table name and structure ... is there any way to get just the data ?

what should i do to optimize my symfony app

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks very abstract. It's very hard to help you without more info. Anyway, I think you should take a look to this question and search about Doctrine hydration options:
[What is Doctrine hydration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661762/what-is-doctrine-hydration).

Remember to use the symfony debug web bar.